# converting tex to xdoc using pandoc (math formulas are not converted)

Tags: conversion, pandoc, msword, word-to-latex, latex-to-word

I just started using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) and I followed every step in [this page](http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html#step-6-converting-a-file).
First of all we create a text file named `test1.md.txt`

```
# Test!

This is a test of *pandoc*.

- list one
- list two
```

Convert it to a `tex` file using the code:

```
pandoc test1.md.txt -s -o test1.tex
```

we get:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={},
            pdftitle={},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\date{}

% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{Test!}\label{test}

This is a test of \emph{pandoc}.

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  list one
\item
  list two
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

When we try to convert this final `tex` file to a `docx` file, its done appropriately:

```
pandoc test1.tex -s -o test1.docx
```

we get the result as:

### [image]

but now I have my own `tex` code named as `equation.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 T_4 &= \langle \underline{k}\,.\,\underline{k}^{*^T} \rangle=
   \left\langle
   \begin{bmatrix}
     |k_1|^2 & k_1k_2^* & k_1k_3^* & k_1k_4^* \\
     k_2k_1^* & |k_2|^2 & k_2k_3^* & k_2k_4^* \\
     k_3k_1^* & k_3k_2^* & |k_3|^2 & k_3k_4^* \\
     k_4k_1^* & k_4k_2^* & k_4k_3^* & |k_4|^2
   \end{bmatrix}
   \right\rangle \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}
   \left[\begin{matrix}
     \langle|S_{XX}+S_{YY}|^2\rangle &
     \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &\\
     \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle &
     \langle|S_{XX}-S_{YY}|^2\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
     \langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle&
     \langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
     \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle &
     \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &
   \end{matrix}\right. \nonumber \\
 & \phantom{{}= \frac{1}{2}}
   \left.\begin{matrix}
     & \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
     & \langle -j(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
     \cdots\cdots& \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
     & \langle -j(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
     \cdots\cdots& \langle|S_{XY}+S_{YX}|^2\rangle
     & \langle-j(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
     & \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
     & \langle|S_{XY}-S_{YX}|^2\rangle
   \end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

And try to convert it to a `docx` file:

```
pandoc equation.tex -s -o equation.docx
```

I get the result:
[image]
This code is fine when used in latex and it does produce the proper `pdf` file
[image]

why doesn't pandoc create the write `docx` file and it just writes the latex codes in the `docx` file?

Comment: I suspect that your equation is too complex for `pandoc` to parse. Do you *really* need this formula in Word, or could you also import it as a figure?

Comment: @Habi in scientific papers they need editable equations. Will it be too complex for htlatex, too? then we can never convert complex equations from tex to word? Should we start using latex from scratch?

Comment: @Habi seems that this equation is too complex for pandoc but not for htlatex. I created an html file by htlatex and then opened the file with word. But you know seems that htlatex just produces an image of the equation not the mathml code. the code that I used is `htlatex file.tex html "--interaction=nonstopmode"`. Seems that there's no way. even htlatex produces an image of the equation not mathml code?!!!!

Comment: I think the whole problem is that the equation is too complicated to be converted from tex to docx!!!!

Comment: Re: "Should we start using latex from scratch?" Yes, indeed that's what I (and probably others here) would suggest for equations that are that complicated. For *all* the manuscripts I ever submitted I was sending the Journal a PDF, so I did my (less complicated) equations in `LaTeX`.

Comment: You *will* have to treat one format of your document as source, the other formats (be it PDF, DOC, HTML) as result. Having "editable equations" in all the possible output formats is probably too far-fetched (and even impossible for certain formats) to achieve.